# How can I get Elo ratings?

Tags: fide, rating

How do I get Elo rating done for myself officially?
Do I contact a FIDE area representative?
Many of the users of this site mention their Elo ratings, how did you get these?

Answer (score 7):

To get an official FIDE rating, you need to compete in tournaments which are FIDE rated. At least in the US, it's more common for tournaments to be just USCF rated, while larger events will also FIDE rate the top section(s).